# my angularjs ng-repeat doesn't work with controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<body ng-app>
    <ul ng-controller='appcontrol'>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yd4VS/2/

try to retrieve item object's name using ng-controller, no luck

Comment: the guy who flagged down, show yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS syntax is incorrect. Try this:

```
function appcontrol($scope){
    $scope.items = [{
        'name': 'shoe',
        'color' : 'blue',
        'price': '200',
    }];
}
```

note that I've wrapped `items` in an array `[]`, and you were missing a `=` sign. Also, very important, on jsFiddle, angular will only work with *No Wrap - in `<head>`* set under Frameworks & Extensions.

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hzU7y/

EDIT: Here is an example of the array with more items:

```
$scope.items = [
    {
        'name': 'shoe',
        'color' : 'blue',
        'price': '200',
    },
    {
        'name': 'shirt',
        'color' : 'pink',
        'price': '150',
    },
    {
        'name': 'shorts',
        'color' : 'denim',
        'price': '120',
    }
];
```

This is probably the most natural way to use ng-repeat as it is repeating over a collection. Or, you could do something similar to what is mentioned in your comment by using a key value pair:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app>
    <ul ng-controller='appcontrol'>
        <li ng-repeat="(id, item) in items"> //<- note difference in the ng-repeat tag
            {{ item.color }} {{ item.name }} at $ {{ item.price }}
         </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function appcontrol($scope){
$scope.items = {
    'item1' : {
        'name': 'shoe',
        'color' : 'blue',
        'price': '200',
    },
    'item2' :{
        'name': 'shirt',
        'color' : 'pink',
        'price': '150',
    },
    'item3' :{
        'name': 'shorts',
        'color' : 'denim',
        'price': '120',
    }};
}
```

Comment: Well, I assume that if you want to iterate over `items`, then `items` should be an array.

Comment: can it be like item = {item1:{},item2:{}} ??

Comment: Have added an update to explain the array and give you an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same as SimonC but with another cleanup and added ng-app name as recommended

html:

```
<body>
  <div id='content' ng-app='MyTutorialApp' ng-controller='MainController'>
    <ul ng-controller='appcontrol'>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

and js :

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);

app.controller("AppController", function($scope){
    $scope.items{
        'name': 'shoe',
        'color' : 'blue',
        'price': '200';
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yd4VS/4/